# How to download file using dropbox

Tags: java, android, dropbox-api

I'm trying to build an app that gives my users right to download file from my dropbox storage.

So I've got next quesions:

1) I was following the dropbox [tutorial](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/android) and it says:

> If the Dropbox app is installed, the SDK will switch to it so the user
>   doesn't have to sign in, and it will fallback to the browser if not.

If I run my app, it will open a browser with dropbox web site. Is there any way to avoid that?

2) Is it possible to download file by file name only? Can I just set url for my storage and file name without randomized url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the dropbox public folder for downloading the file that you want. You just have to put the file in that folder and then copy the url.
Then on you java you just have to put the code to download from a URL.
This is how I have done in my program and it doesn't open any browser.
A good thing about the URL in Public folder, is that it doesn't change if the filename doesn't change, so you can update your file and the URL will be the same

Comment: yes, the api only gives you the oportunity to upload files. But if you can upload the files manually there is no need for the dropbox API

Comment: when i had a program that uploaded a file, i created an online ftp account and made my upload there. if need help in that i can give you some pointers

Comment: to copy the file URL you just have to put the file in the Public folder and then right-click the file and choose "Copy public link"

Comment: Ok-ok, I know it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use client to download file by name

```
    DbxEntry.File md;
    File file = new File("destination.file");
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    try {
        md = client.getFile("/path/to/target.file", null, out);
    } finally {
        out.close();
    }
```

Here `null` indicates that you want to receive the latest revision of file. And `"/path/to/target.file"` is path to file on your dropbox, like `"/Public/001.jpg"`.

Also `md` can be used to retrieve some metadata about this file, like its size, name, revision, etc.